Which distances can I run on my treadmill?
This is a real-world question, prompted by some unusual features on my treadmill and which I thus think about while running.
In a sub-menu on my treadmill, I can select a distance that I want to run.  If my unit setting is "miles", the distances offered are all multiples of 0.1 miles, but not all multiples are possible!  Specifically, if I increase the distance iteratively, the first eight available options are (in units of miles): 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0.  As you can see, the distances 0.3mi and 0.8mi are missing!
I decided to collect more data on which distances are possible.  It seems easier to work with integer sequences, so for the purposes of this problem, I imagine working in multiples of tenths of a mile (decimile?).  Then, the distances up to 100 that cannot be chosen are:
$$ 3, 8, 13, 18, 23, 28, 33, 38, 44, 49, 54, 59, 64, 69, 74, 79, 84, 90, 95, 100. $$
As you can see, the missing distances are usually 5 apart, except sometimes they are 6 apart.  I checked as high as I can and this pattern continues.  If I just record the missing distances that are 6 higher than the previous missing distance, I get these six before the treadmill refuses to give me distances longer than a marathon:
$$ 44,90,131,172,218,259. $$
I now have a few questions:

How are these possible distances being generated?  What is the rule, pattern, or program?

Given a distance (like 49, meaning 4.9mi), how can I mathematically determine whether the distance can be selected?

Asymptotically, what proportion of distances cannot be selected?


(Note: the same restrictions on my treadmill also apply to speeds, expressed in mph, so for example 10mph cannot be selected.)

If you round the miles converted from every 200 meters you seem to get that sequence. But that does seem absurd so i leave it as a comment.

The distances between the $6$s seem to be (roughly) constant, which suggests a division with rounding. Maybe @RollenS.D'Souza is on the right track (or the right treadmill),

@EthanBolker: I wonder whether those successive differences are all either 46 or 41!

@RollenS.D'Souza I suspect you are correct, as 200m is the length of a standard indoor track.

@BenjaminKuykendall Wow, neat! That would probably explain it.

Fortunately, it looks like every multiple of $0.1$ miles is the sum of two distances that your treadmill can manage. So, here is a new thing for you to think about as you run: How should I write my preferred distance as a sum of two treadmill numbers?

@rollen-s-dsouza is correct -- the underlying math is metric, at 200m increments, and the output is converted to miles.
A tenth of a mile is 160.9344m. You can look at values of $\text{round}(\frac{200x}{160.9344})$ and get the exact pattern you observed.
That's not very surprising -- the people responsible for customizing the treadmill for sale in a specific region are probably not the same people writing most its control software.
From here on, let $I=\frac{200}{160.9344} \approx 1.242742$ be our symbol for the increment, in tenths-of-a-mile.
Part 2 A number will appear in the progression if it's close enough to a multiple of $I$. -- specifically, if a multiple lands within 0.05 miles of the desired number.
The nearest multiple can be calculated as follows, if $x$ is in units of 0.1mi, then, $y=I \cdot \text{round}(\frac x I)$. You can then look at $|y-x|$ and see whether it's less than 0.5.
Part 3
We know that the asymptotic slope is $I$ -- so when we get to 100 steps, we've seen 100 numbers but our displayed value is near $100I \approx 124$. So we skipped about 24. The exact formula is $\frac{I-1}{I}=0.195328$ ratio of numbers skipped.

@A.Rex sorry, I meant to follow up with answers earlier. My answer has been updated with the other parts.

This looks like it works, thanks!  (Nit: $\lvert{y-x}\rvert$ instead of $y-x$, I think?)  It seems like this stuff is related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence#Rayleigh_theorem

There's a theorem known as Rayleigh's theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence) - for irrational numbers $r, s$ with $1/r + 1/s = 1$, the sequences ${\lfloor r \rfloor, \lfloor 2r \rfloor, \lfloor 3r \rfloor, \lfloor 4r \rfloor, \ldots}$ and ${\lfloor s \rfloor, \lfloor 2s \rfloor, \lfloor 3s \rfloor, \lfloor 4s \rfloor, \ldots}$ contain between them every positive integer exactly once.
This appears to generalize such that your sequence of distances which cannot be chosen are $J/2, 3J/2, 5J/2, \ldots$ rounded to the nearest integer, where $I = 200/160.9344$ as defined by @AlexK and $J = I/(I-1) \approx 5.120773$.  This is a generalization both in that we're dealing with rounding instead of floors and that $I, J$ are rational.

I just said it "appears to generalize", and people seem to like this - I'm going to have to prove this now.
